# The level of PHP questions is frankly quite low, can we do something about it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, question-quality

I'm mostly a PHP guy but it's only recently that I started looking at the PHP tag and the level of the questions is really poor.

With poor I mean that, apart from answering the question, you usually have to point out SQL Injection problems and XSS problems.

Can't we do a "community wiki" question like "What every PHP developer should read before asking a question on Stack Overflow" that points out to good resources on common topics like SQL Injection, XSS, Encoding, how to avoid notices and warnings and so on? Is this something  worth doing or not?

Comment: Tag Wikis? And yes, I know that visibility is bad...

Comment: Why don't you write it up as your own blog post. You can then point people at it in a comment on these bad questions.

Comment: @Chris i will surely write some blog posts on the topic, i was wondering if doing something like this question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development would help

Comment: That's an old question that was migrated from Stack Overflow - I wouldn't use it as justification to post something new on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Kobobby yes tag wiki are what i'm looking for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can't we do a "community wiki" question

[**No.**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

> like "What every PHP developer should read before asking a question on Stack Overflow" that points out to good resources on common topics

[**God no.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128561#128561)

Perhaps updating the [PHP tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) is what you really want to do, but as you can see, it's already pretty comprehensive.

Comment: That "what Stack Overflow is not" page is turning out to be quite useful.

Comment: @AdamRackis Indeed, it is.  I've already seen *many* comments on the main site referencing it on questions/answers that are flagged.  It's a great resource.

Comment: Didn't think about tag wiki, if it's done right it's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @AdamRackis And are you checking up on me?  I think I'm within 400-500 rep of you?  Who will hit 10K first?  Stay tuned to find out.

Comment: @casper - right now I've got 9 days left in my job before I start my awesome new one.  Right now I'm writing a SQL UDF for a mainframe programmer who...can't.  Part of me wants to dive into MSO, and part of me wants to just go to Starbucks and read all day.  Stay tuned to see whatt *I* end up doing...

Comment: @AdamRackis Well, I'm going to the Yankee's home opener for the next four hours, enjoy, as I *definitely* won't be on meta then.  Laters!

Comment: Be careful in the Bronx...I hear the people from there are just *awful*

Comment: @Adam Depends, but I hear me and my clan's rep is pretty tight.

Comment: That "What SO is not" page is an elaborate set up by Robert to Harveyst bazillion gold badges =)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that the general level of questions under the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag is pretty poor. I spend most of my time on that tag and a lot of the questions are very basic. However, I do not agree that creating a wiki will help.

I think part of the problem is that the low barrier to entry for PHP makes it a popular language for beginners and amateurs. I used to fall into both camps, but now I hope its only the latter.

Nobody posting on SO for the first (second or third) time is going to read the tag wiki or any community wiki, they don't even read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page when faced with it for their first question. Its only when you get interested in being a part of the SO community that you read that stuff.

My strategy has been to try and point out when people are trying to do something that is poor practice. If I answer such a question I will try and point out why doing what they are doing is not a good idea and present a better option. [I have been down voted for it occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766541/212940), but that's OK.

I also down vote answers that encourage poor practice and up vote those that encourage good practice.

Remember that (most) users don't post poor questions intentionally. Look at it as an opportunity to teach them how to do something properly and point them at resources that encourage good programming practices.

If we all do the same, maybe we can raise the standard of questions under the [php](/questions/tagged/php)tag.

I notice the [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag seems to be going the same way lately, so maybe my optimism is misplaced.

Comment: Yes i agree with you but sometimes there are so many basic errors in the question that i felt that i neede a single place where to point users to so that they can (if they want) correct the most obvious problems. Three days ago my cousin asked me if i could take a look at his site and i discovered that PASSWORD were not crypted. And the site had been done by a "programmer".

Comment: (OT, but @NicolaPeluchetti, if you're going to complain about the quality of anything, please, for the love of English, _capitalize your `I`s_. I, always, never i.)

Comment: @Mat you are right!!!! :P